# Data structure with fast indexOf?

Tags: java, data-structures, indexing

I need an ordered data structure with O(1) indexOf operation. I store object pointers in the data structure. Any ideas? Some sort of LinkedHashMap?

See what "indexOf" means: [`List.indexOf(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is ambiguous to begin with.

1. It would be nice if you could qualify what you mean by fast `indexOf(..)` operation.
2. What kind of objects are you going to store in the collection?
3. Is finding the `indexOf(..)` the only responsibility of the collection.

Simply put, one way to do this would be to maintain a  that would index each `Object` or keys with the list of indices.

```
HashMap<Object, List<Integer>>
```

Again, this is vague, probably would help if you specify the exact nature of problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Then why not have another data structure that stores references to each object in the original list?

Comment: I have to maintain HashMap<Object, List<Integer>> each time I insert or remove objects from the main data structure? Isnt there such one data structure to do this.

Comment: By a datastructure you mean in Java collections - then No. If you mean if there is a User-Defined data structure or means to do it then of course.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) being the reference implementation. The performance is `log(n)`, and that's probably the best you are going to get using lookup in an ordered structure (at least in standard libraries).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a skip list or a balanced tree, you can get O(log n) for `insert` and `indexOf`.

If you maintain a sorted `List<Object>` to store the items you want to track, along with a `HashMap<Object, Integer>` to store the starting position of each item, you can get O(1) `indexOf` in exchange for O(n) `insert`.

I haven't thought about it deeply, but I don't think it's possible to get O(1) insert and O(log n) indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

try using PriorityQueue instead to make it oredered...

Comment: ? HashMaps arent even ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Store the Object as both key and value in HashMap. I am assuming that you are looking to retrieve object eventually.